# I keep receiving this error Error: EACCES: permission denied, when I am trying to npm install react-navigation

Tags: macos, terminal, permissions

I tried sudo installing and manually changing the permissions via Finder, but none of that work. I am not sure why install react-navigation isn't accessible.

npm ERR! path /Users/Desktop/RutgersCapstone/rutgersCap/node_modules
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! syscall access
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/Users/Desktop/RutgersCapstone/rutgersCap/node_modules'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/Users/Desktop/RutgersCapstone/rutgersCap/node_modules']
npm ERR!   stack:
npm ERR!    'Error: EACCES: permission denied, access \'/Users/Desktop/RutgersCapstone/rutgersCap/node_modules\'',
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'access',
npm ERR!   path:
npm ERR!    '/Users/Desktop/RutgersCapstone/rutgersCap/node_modules' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator (though this is not recommended).

Answer (score 0):

I tried npm cache clean and then tried installing with 
sudo npm install [command] and it worked for me.